# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gistry.npmjs.org/loda'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Getting this error continuously while creating react app using create-react-app... 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\reactjscrashcourse>npx create-react-app routing
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gistry.npmjs.org/loda'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-26T14_57_52_086Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

C:\Users\User\Desktop\reactjscrashcourse>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.